# Steps to enable the print screen key using edit registry in window 10

Tags: windows-10, window

I have disabled the PrintScreen using the link 
[disable the printscreen keyboard option from windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083031/disable-the-printscreen-keyboard-option-from-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming nothing else has been changed it should be pretty simple:

Navigate to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout

In the right pane, right-click and delete Scancode Map (so we just remove the thing you added).

Then close and restart.